# 10 points outside a unit circle

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Let $P_1$, $P_2$,... $P_{10}$ be ten points outside the unit circle centered at the origin $O$. Given that $\|P_iP_j\|\ge 1/\sqrt{2}$ for all $1\le 1<j\le 10$,  find the minimum of the sum of the distances from $O$ to the points $P_i$, that is,

$$minimize\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10} \|OP_i\|\right)$$

MAPLE gives a minimum of $11.441\ldots$ when the points are the vertices of a regular decagon centered at $O$. I would like to see a standard proof of this result. Even a lower bound of about $11.32$ would be sufficient for my purposes.

The problem is connected to a 1951 paper of Bateman and Erdos that appeared in Amer. Math. Monthly ['Geometrical Extrema Suggested by a Lemma of Besicovitch'](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1951-03.pdf).

Comment: "It is known that..." I would like the demonstration, because if I want to put two points in less 0.1 of distance I can do it...

Comment: @Shadock I am pretty sure the "It is known..." statement is just a statement of the problem's constraints.

Comment: Maybe the question text could be changed from "known" to "given"? Is $P_iP_j$ the same as $P_j-P_i$?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your motivation behind getting a solution, especially such that "even a lower bound of $11.32$ would be sufficient"?

Comment: Using the second set up in my answer, you can get lower than $10.76$, and I am not sure that is optimal to this point.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider the following image:

[image]

Each of the black circles represents the minimum distance points must be away from each other. The blue circle is the unit circle.

Notice that moving any **single** point out of this configuration necessarily either places a point into the unit circle or increases the sum of distances to the origin.

---

Edit: There is no rigorous proof for the decagon because there is at least one configuration that has a lesser sum. Consider the following image:

[image]

Notice that $8$ of the points are on the unit circle. Also notice that placing a point on the "outer boundary" of any of the black circles will yield a point that is $\le1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ away from the origin. (EDIT) Repeating for the tenth point such that it is still the appropriate distance from the ninth and is on one of the eight circles, the increase is the same. (end EDIT) From this, you get a configuration whose sum is $\le11.416$, which is less than the decagon.

Comment: I agree with you this is a local optimum. How do I know it is global?

Comment: @user84909 That's a very good question. Basically, it should be clear (or fairly easy to show) this is an optimization problem where the minimum occurs on the boundary (equality) of one or more of the inequality constraints, However just given that, it's not clear whether it will be some of the $d(D_i,D_j) \geq 1/\sqrt{2}$ constraints that will be turned into equalities, or $d(D_i,O) \geq 1$ constraints that will be turned into equalities, or both. If you could show that it is a maximal number of $d(D_i,D_j) \geq 1/\sqrt{2}$ inequalities that turn into equalities, then you would be done.

Comment: @user2566092 I played with it a little more, thanks to your comment, and found a smaller value. Thanks for the input.

Comment: That only gives you nine points, not ten.

Comment: @Michael I felt like it was implied that the tenth point would also be placed on one of the circles (in a way not interfering with the ninth, of course). Editing to reflect that now.

Comment: @Terra Hyde: great example Terra! So MAPLE is lying! You cannot trust these computers... So it is more to this problem than it meets the eye.

Comment: I thought about this a while (also @user84909 ) and it seems like the complication is that we are minimizing a sum of distances, as opposed to say, a sum of SQUARED distances. If it were sum of squared distance, then I think any regular decagon circumscribing the unit circle would be an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

The target function is continuous and we can restrict the domain to points in the compact annulus $1\le r\le 3$. Hence the minimum of the function is attained. Therefore it suffices to show for any configuration that is *not* a regular decagon centered at $O$ and with side length $1/\sqrt 2$, there exists a better configuration. This way you can readily show that any configuration where not every point has two neighbours at distance exactly $1/\sqrt 2$ is suboptimal. After that, if you have four consecutive points $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ where $\|OP_2\|>||OP_1\|$, say, then it should not be too hard to show that this configuration can be improved by moving $P_2$ and $P_3$ ...

Comment: "Where not every point has 2 neighbors that are" and "if you have 4 consecutive points" seems to suggest the points are in convex position, although that isn't explicitly shown to be a requirement for an optimal solution inside your annulus. Is there an easy way to see it? Or is there a way to interpret your hints so that points don't have to be in convex position?